# Grub will not boot to windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, grub, bootloader, grub2

I recently installed Ubuntu with the grub boot loader that comes with it. After the install Grub fails to find the Windows.

**My setup:**

- HD1 & HD2 -> Samsung SSDs in Raid0 via Motherboard containing Windows (and probably a partition for windows recovery)
- HD 3 -> (3TB Western Digitral) Containing two paritions: Ubuntu / NTFS (if I remember correctly, just with files, not bootable)
- HD4 -> NTFS with files

**The error:**

When loading up grub I am presented with four options:

- Ubuntu
- Advanced options for Ubuntu
- Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/mapper/pdc_dagafhccb1)
- Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/mapper/pdc_dagafhccb2)

Selecting either of those windows options will provide similar errors:

```
error: no such device: 966027106026F721
error: unknown argument `hidden-'.

Press any key to continue...
```

**Things I have tried:**

I have never needed to manipulate the boot loader until now as they typically just worked like magic and got the job done without my help. Going into the command line for grub I typed in `ls` which promptly showed me all my drives. The ls utility for grub was not able to recognize a MSDOS Windows partition (or any windows partition). However I do know that the hard drive is intact since I can mount the volume and read files perfectly from the windows partition.

Online sources I found highly recommended an automated utility to scan and fix the grub partition called `boot-repair`. I installed and followed its instructions with no luck in repairing the boot loader from recognizing the partition as a boot-able entity. I have tried this about 15 times with varying modifications to its settings. The last log from the utility is http://paste2.org/6OEaEMnt.

The logs (from what I can gather) show that sda1 through 3 could not be mounted and read `Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''` Which would make sense if utility was trying to access the disk independently of the Motherboards RAID System (? yet again, little experience on how the RAID is actually set up and performed, I just know that both drives are plugged into the Motherboard and set up for RAID0).
`sdc2` Appears to be the Windows partition since it found `Windows 7/2008: NTFS`.

You can also see what it set grubs launch script for Windows to:

```
menuentry 'Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/mapper/pdc_dagafhccb1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-94F01FB0F01F9796' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  94F01FB0F01F9796
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 94F01FB0F01F9796
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
```

Part of the command makes sense to me, but a lot of the command does not due to lack of experience. So debugging this thing on my own would be futile. One of the largest concerns I have is how it found the magic number: `94F01FB0F01F9796`. That is beyond me.  It is also the error that I presume is stopping me from loading the windows partition (potentially among others).

I might be missing more options to tell grub that this partition is a RAID, it might be loading in a misaligned sector of the disk with the magic number, I am honestly unsure. I am hoping the internet can save my sorry computer.

--EDIT--

BIOS settings:

- Hard Disk Boot Priority:

  1. SCSI-0 : SAMSUNG SSD 830 Series
  2. SCSI-1 : SAMSUNG SSD 830 Series
  3. SCSI-2 : ST3000DM001-1CH166
  4. Bootable Add-in Cards
- EFI CD/DVD Boot Option: Auto
- First Boot Device: USB-HDD
- Second Boot Device: LS120
- Third Boot Device: Hard Disk
- HDD S.M.A.R.T. Capability: Enabled
- OnChip SATA Controller: Enabled
- OnChip SATA Type: AHCI
- OnChip SATA Port4/5 Type: As SATA type
- OnChip SATA3.0 Support: Enabled
- F_USB30 Controller: Enabled
- eSATA3 Controller: Enabled
- eSATA3 Ctrl Mode: AHCI

**--Actual RAID Settings--**

Under the RAID Configuration Utility:

View Drive Assignments:

- 01:01 (SSD 830 Series) [SMART] SATA 6G 128.03GB (127.96GB) LD 1-1
- 02:01 (SSD 830 Series) [SMART] SATA 6G 128.03GB (127.96GB) LD 1-1
- 06:01 (ST3000DM001-1CH166) [SMART] SATA 6G 3000.59

LD View Menu:

- LD 1, RAID 0, Drive 2, Capacity 253.99GB, Functional

Controller Configuration:

- Controller IRQ: 11
- AHCI HBA MMIO Base Address: FDFFF000

Comment: Looking the boot repair log the only thing that is clear is that the raid configuration isn't working properly. The cause of that is not clear. Grub appears to be trying to boot windows via sdc but it shouldn't even see sdc or sdb as those are the two physical drives which constitute sda. I would start in the bios and check your raid configuration. Post your motherboard info if you want assistance with that. My best guess is that your motherboard is 'confusing' grub and the repair tool.

Comment: @Argonauts Thanks for replying. I posted some settings info about my BIOS configuration and by RAID setup. I am not exactly sure what you meant with "motherboard is 'confusing' grub and the repair tool" If you can elaborate on that I could investigate further.

Comment: What I meant, using poor phrasing, is that in my experience when you have drives in raid, the raid controller, whether an add-on card or the BIOS will communicate the RAID configuration to applications running at higher levels (grub --> OS --> applications) in such a way that the SW knows to 'not' access the constitute parts of the raid array directly, and to only access device(s) via the RAID controller's 'device'; which in this case is sda. This is why I'm encouraging you to evaluate the raid configuration first. Nothing close to an answer; just a suggestion.

Comment: Can you provide the make / model of the motherboard? Also, if you have any data on any of these drives that is valuable / not backed up elsewhere I would work on that before trying to fix it. Purely opinion here, but if that were my setup, I'd most likely go the nuclear option (full wipe / reinstall). Not to say that there won't be a way to fix it, but that the time spent trying to fix it will be 10x the time to reinstall windows, ubuntu and apps, and be back in a known good state. And I like fixing stuff.

Comment: @Argonauts GIGABYTE GA-990FXA-UD3 AM3+ AMD 990FX SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 ATX AMD Motherboard

Comment: @Argonauts I would like to try a couple of options before I go nuclear and reinstall Windows. Do you have any suggestions for RAID settings to modify?

Comment: I did take a look at the manual for the mobo, there are two raid modes supported - one configured in bios and the other during boot ( hit Ctrl - something to get to the menu). I'm not sure which mode you are using. But regardless, my takeaway was that the the hard drives should be in RAID mode not AHCI mode (which you've stated they are) sometimes raid mode gets listed as ahci \ raid but not in my experience just ahci. The problem is that the drives could get wiped if you do this. Have you updated the bios at all recently? Battery die on the mobo?   Make sure the 2 ssds are on sata 1,2 or 3.

Comment: I would focus on repairing the windows boot without the Ubuntu drive installed. Start with the raid settings and once they seem to be recognized properly you could try the windows boot repair. Again without Ubuntu. Once that works set up grub again to dual boot. You could go the other way also - pull the win drives and get Ubuntu to boot. Just lower the # of variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39421/discussion-between-jakebird451-and-argonauts).